# Parametrization of a parabola inside a cylinder

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, parametrization

So first of all, I would like to say that I wish to confirm whether the parametrization I am doing is correct. I've been told that $x = r\cos t, y = r\sin t, z = z$, which makes me hesitant on my answer.

Paraboloid: $y = x^2 + z^2 \text{ and } x^2 + z^2 = 16$

Which gives us a cylinder and parabola parallel to the $y$-axis with a radius of 4.

I THINK IT SHOULD BE THIS, SINCE THE CIRCLE IS ON THE X-Z PLANE:

$$x = r\cos t, y = y, z = r\sin t$$

Parametrization should be: $\langle r\cos t, y, r\sin t\rangle$

And then when I try to convert the scalar surface integral into the parametrized form in order to find surface area, I would use:

$$\int_{0}^{4}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \delta \text { } |r_t \text{ } x \text{ }r_y|\,\mathrm dt\mathrm dy$$

Can anyone tell me if I'm going on the correct route, or if I'm totally off track?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes. This is correct, except for the typo (with $r$ instead of $z$).

Comment: @TedShifrin Oops, my mistake on that typo! Thank you very much for confirming my work for me.

Comment: Please explain the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: $y=x^2+z^2=(r\cos t)^2+(r\sin t)^2=r^2$. As is, your parameterization captures a cylinder with varying height $y$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I am just trying to have someone clarify the parametrization for me, not solve an entire problem.

Comment: @user170231 Yes, my apologies. I didn't put in the limits of the integral, but I mentioned somewhere in the comments below that I did know what to place. I will edit the post just to clarify and not create confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I missed a bit of what you're doing. You're parametrizing the portion of the paraboloid inside the cylinder, so you need to put $y=r^2$ as your polar-coordinate expression in the parametrization. So the parametrization should be in terms of $r$ and $t$ (with $0\le r\le 4$ and $0\le t\le 2\pi$).

Comment: Shouldn't that be $0\le r\le4$?

Comment: Oops, of course.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $0 \lt r \lt 4$ since the cylinder has a radius of 4, so parabola goes from 0 to 4 as t goes from 0 to $2\pi$
Edit: oh looks like you editted it, and yes I know the limits of the integrals, I just mainly wanted to confirm on the parametrization itself so I can proceed with the integral problem. Thank you!

Comment: Wait, a moment, would $y=r^2$ be what I put for $<rcost, r^2, rsint>$?

Comment: Yes, right. You have to put in what makes the equation of the paraboloid. I wasn't paying attention to the details of the problem originally.

Comment: Hmm...I find this a bit confusing, I know that since the equation of the cylinder is $x^2 + z^2 = 16$, parametrized it would be: $r^2 = 16 \Rightarrow r = 4$.

But is $y = y$ not correct when converting to cylindrical coordinates? I'm looking back at my notes for a parabola perpendicular to the z-axis and I see that my teacher put $\gamma = <x,y,z> \Rightarrow \gamma = <rcost, rsint, z>$

Comment: If you were setting up a triple integral in cylindrical coordinates, then $y$ would stay as $y$, as we agreed originally. But you're parametrizing a portion of the paraboloid $y=x^2+z^2$. So, when we set $x=r\cos t$ and $z=r\sin t$, we have $y=r^2$.

Comment: Hm, that is weird. The integral mentioned in my previous comment with my professor is also only a double integral, so I'm not sure why he only had z = z. I understand what you are saying though.